# Error 404 al conectar ASP.NET Core 6 Y Angular

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Estoy creando una aplicación con .net core 6, pero tengo error al realizar la consulta, lo primero que realice fue conectarme a la base de datos en creada con SQL Server, instale los paquetes :

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
4. Cree la carpeta Models

Como utilizare una base de datos existente abrí la consola de administrador de paquetes NuGet, y procedí con el siguiente comando:

```
Scaffold-DbContext “Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx” Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Después abrí el Archivo que contiene el context, y procedí a mandar mi cadena de conexión al archivo **appsettings.json**, dejándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConexionBD": "Server=xxxxx;Database=Cotizador;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Y como estoy trabajando con la versión de 6 de .Net, realice a agregar a las siguientes lineas de código en **Program.cs**, con la finalidad de mantener la cadena de conexión fuera del archivo DBContext, siendo así:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CotizadorContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConexionBD"));
});
```

De ahí agregue un Controlador MVC en blanco en la carpeta Controllers, y agregue el siguiente código:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CotizadorV3.Models;
using CotizadorV3.Clases;

namespace CotizadorV3.Controllers
{
    public class ClientesController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Clientes/listaClientes")]
        public IEnumerable<ClienteCLS> listaClientes()
        {
            using (CotizadorContext bd = new CotizadorContext())
            {
                List<ClienteCLS> clientes = (from c in bd.Clientes
                                             select new ClienteCLS
                                             {
                                                 NombreCliente = c.NombreCliente,
                                             }).ToList();
                return clientes;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y poner `https://localhost:44458/api/listaClientes` en Postmat me sale error 404

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se que esta mal, ya que en 3.1 funciona bien, realizando estos procesos.

Actualización:

Hice uso de este comando,`Add-Migration "Version 1.1"` y si se conecta y lo genera sin ningún problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUCIÓN

Cuando migras/actualizas o creas un proyecto con .NET CORE 6, este hace cambios radicales para proyectos como las web apis y demás. tenia un proyecto con .NET 2.1 pero empezo a dar errores y evalue pasarlo a .net 6 el incoveniente es que al generarlo y empezar a hacer consultas con consumo de la api, al intentar consumirla este nunca entraba, revisando y consultando varios foros y documentación de Microsoft, este me llevo al siguiente [enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022).

En la parte fundamental del que me di una idea fue en el párrafo:

> Go to the launchSettings.json file in your ASP.NET Core project (in
> the Properties folder). Get the port number from the applicationUrl
> property.
>
> If there are multiple applicationUrl properties, look for one using an
> https endpoint. It should look similar to https://localhost:7049.
>
> Then, go to the proxy.conf.js file for your Angular project (look in
> the src folder). Update the target property to match the
> applicationUrl property in launchSettings.json. When you update it,
> that value should look similar to this:

Hace mencion que deben de coincidir lo mismo con respecto a los URL's, cosa que angular ya hace con la linea :

```
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:57275';
```

Para poder llegar al anterior bloque de codigo este se encuentra en ClientApp y esta nombrado como **proxy.conf.js**, originalmente esta así :

const { env } = require('process');

```
const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:57275';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Para ir agregando controladores se deben de tomar el nombre colocado antes del controller, ejemplo: ***ClienteController.cs***, se tomara ***Cliente***

y este se agrega al bloque:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/Cliente"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]
```

Y de manera, cada que se declaren Controladores, esto debe de hacerse, **en Web Api's**, antes iban `api/{NombreControlador}/Acción`, ahora es `{NombreControlador}/Acción`

y en su controlador deben configurar lo así, sea MVC/Api:

```
namespace CotizadorWebV1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("Cliente")] //Sera la ruta que debe de ser igual al declarado al anterior

    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CotizadorContext _context;

        public ClienteController(CotizadorContext context)
        {
            _context = context; 
        }
        //La declaración anterior es, porque definí la conexión a la BD, en appsettings.json

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("listaClientes")]
        public IEnumerable<Cliente> listaClientes()
        {
            using(CotizadorContext bd = _context)
            {
                List<Cliente> Lista = (from c in bd.Clientes
                                          select new Cliente
                                          {
                                            NombreCliente = c.NombreCliente,
                                          }).ToList();
                return Lista;
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

Y finalmente la ruta para consultarlo en postmant seria asi:

```
https://localhost:44486/Cliente/listaClientes
```

y así se obtiene los datos sin errores

Comment: Amigo, me alegra de corazón que hayas resuelto tu caso :D Sigue adelante; por otro lado te comparto unos detalles que considero importantes: la pregunta está totalmente ajena con esta respuesta, en ningún lado mencionaste que `Cuando migras/actualizas o creas un proyecto con .NET CORE 6`, al poner `migrar`, todo el escenario es diferente a partir de ese punto, solo dijiste: `Estoy creando una aplicación con .net core 6`, además lo enfocaste en Postman y aquí mencionas conexión desde javascript. ¿Sería mucho pedir que sigas los lineamientos del sitio por favor?

Comment: El detalle fue que al investigar algunos caso eran similar cuando migraban a la versión 5 y casi todos coincidían que si migraban tenían que hacer algo similar, por eso lo incluí ya que en mi caso era crearla desde cero

Comment: Normal, el punto es simple, lee nuevamente ambos comentarios, el que dejé en la respuesta que te ofrecí y el que dejé líneas arriba. Aquí unas recomendaciones finales: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 eres libre de aceptarlas, rechazarlas o ignorarlas. Saludos :D

Comment: could you use a wildcard like context: [
      "/api/*"
   ],

Answer (score 0):

Considerando los datos de la pregunta.

**En el controlador:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Clientes/listaClientes")]
```

**En Postman:**

Estás apuntando a `api/listaClientes`

**Solución:**

Utilizar la URL `api/Clientes/listaClientes`

Comment: En parte tenias razón, porque apuntaba a otro lado, ahorita adjunto la respuesta correcta! :D

Comment: 2 cosas: 1. Si esta respuesta solucionó el error mencionado en la pregunta, márcala como aceptada. 2. Si a raíz de lo que hiciste, te generó un nuevo error y este error se aleja de la pregunta original, retoma el punto anterior y crea una nueva pregunta, a esa nueva pregunta, agrega la solución que hiciste detallando los pasos que utilizaste. Saludos.